# Turn list of variables into an array

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode

Is there any way to turn this list of variables into an array? They all still need to hold their data type of UIImage! I just have no idea how I might be able to do this.

Thanks in advance.
Might I add...i'm still very knew to learning swift and it is my first language. But Im having a pretty hard time learning to work out these kinds of problems on my own and understanding the concepts. So any tips and pointers would be great.

```
    a0 = UIImage(named: "0.png")
    a1 = UIImage(named: "1.png")
    a2 = UIImage(named: "2.png")
    a3 = UIImage(named: "3.png")
    a4 = UIImage(named: "4.png")
    a5 = UIImage(named: "5.png")
    a6 = UIImage(named: "6.png")
    a7 = UIImage(named: "7.png")
    a8 = UIImage(named: "8.png")
    a9 = UIImage(named: "9.png")
    a10 = UIImage(named: "10.png")
    a11 = UIImage(named: "11.png")
    a12 = UIImage(named: "12.png")
    a13 = UIImage(named: "13.png")
    a14 = UIImage(named: "14.png")
    a15 = UIImage(named: "15.png")
    a16 = UIImage(named: "16.png")
    a17 = UIImage(named: "17.png")
    a18 = UIImage(named: "18.png")
    a19 = UIImage(named: "19.png")
    a20 = UIImage(named: "20.png")
```

Comment: Yes you can. Check https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Why don't you create an Array in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Declare an array a that will hold your images collection
var a:[UIImage] = []

//Bad way - if the image doesn't exist you will get a crash by force unwrapping the UIImage optional
for i in 0...20 {
    a.append(UIImage(named: "\(i).png")!)
}

//Less bad way - check if the image exists before adding it to the array, but you might end up with an array of less than 20 elements if some images are missing
for i in 0...20 {
    if let image = UIImage(named: "\(i).png") {
        a.append(image)
    }
}

//Maybe what you look for
for i in 0...20 {
    if let image = UIImage(named: "\(i).png") {
        a.append(image)
    }
    else {
        a.append(UIImage(named: "placeholderImage.png")!) //placeholderImage.png is an image that will replace your missing image. In this case you can force unwrap it (!) because you are sure the image is within your assets
    }
}

//Later on to access the variable you can do this for example

let image7 = a[7]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use for loop and no need to write '.png' extension when take image.

```
var images: [UIImage?] = []
for index in 0...20 {
    images.append(UIImage(named: "\(index)"))
}
```

Or with using map function

```
let images = (0...20).map { UIImage(named: "\($0)") }
```

Answer (score 0):

### You can create array as following

```
let array = (0...20).map { UIImage(named: "\($0).png") }
```

Then for getting value can add extension

```
extension Array {
    func get(at index: Int) -> Element? {
         guard self.indices.contains(index) else { return nil }
         return self[index]
    }
}
```

And get it

```
let image5 = array.get(at: 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
let imageLsit = (0...20).map{ UIImage(named: "\($0)") }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a array of UIImage

```
 var imageArr = [UIImage]()
```

to add new object in this Array you can use `.Append(...)`

```
imageArr.append(UIImage(named: "0.png")!)
```

or

```
imageArr.append(a0) ...
```

and you can use a for loop to add the rest of images.

Answer (score 0):

As shown on the code snippet the image name has the pattern for its name by starting from 0 to n (in your case n is equal to 20) the simple solution may be to create `UIImage` object inside a loop from 0 to n then append it into an array of `UIImage`.

## Solution

### 1. Using for loop

```
var images: [UIImage] = []
for i in 0...20 {
    // Append image if UIImage not nil
    if let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "\(i)") {
        images.append(image)
    }
}
```

### 2. Using compactMap

Another solution, you may use higher order function such as [`compactMap`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2950916-compactmap) in this case. `compactMap` will only append nonnil value into returned from the block. As a result you will get the list of nonnil UIImage only.

```
let images: [UIImage] = (0...20).compactMap { (index: Int) -> UIImage? in
    return UIImage(named: "\(index)")
}
```

## Notes

If you want to keep track of your image and sync the image name with the image index in the list I suggest you to use `[UIImage?]`. You may need this as `UIImage(named: String)` may return `nil` value if image with the name given doesn't exist.

```
var images: [UIImage?] = []
for i in 0...20 {
    let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "\(i)")
    images.append(image)
}
```